# How to ignore lines using JUnit 5's @CsvFileSource

Tags: csv, junit5

I am using `@CsvFileSource` annotation of JUnit 5 to parameterize my test cases, but I am not able to ignore the comments from in the CSV file.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Example CSV:

```
apple fruit sweet
carrot vegetable sweet
// lemon vegetable sour  (Ignore this)
banana fruit sweet
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a `#` at the beginning of the comment lines:

```
apple, fruit, sweet
carrot, vegetable, sweet
# lemon, vegetable, sour
banana, fruit, sweet
```

Comment: I can confirm that is the correct solution, even if it's not documented as such. ;-)

Comment: If you want to skip the first N lines, you can achieve that by specifying N via the `numLinesToSkip` attribute of `@CsvFileSource(resources = ..., numLinesToSkip = ...)`.

Comment: FYI: I raised the following issue to address the lack of documentation for this feature. https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1782